# How can I detect two different sets of ibeacon UUID at the same time?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

This is my current approach, but my tableview cell only shows a kind of uuid ,
What should I do?

```
    class iBeaconListVC: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let lm = CLLocationManager()
    var beaconsArray = [CLBeacon]()

    let uuid1 = UUID(uuidString: "FDA50693-A4E2-4FB1-AFCF-C6EB07647825")
    let uuid2 = UUID(uuidString: "AB8190D5-D11E-4941-ACC4-42F30510B408")

    var beaconRegion1: CLBeaconRegion!
    var beaconRegion2: CLBeaconRegion!

    @IBOutlet weak var baconsListTV: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        lm.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        lm.delegate = self

        let beaconRegion1 = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid1!, identifier: "beacon1")
        let beaconRegion2 = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid2!, identifier: "beacon2")


        lm.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion1)
        lm.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion2)

    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        self.beaconsArray.removeAll()
        if beacons.count > 0 {
            beaconsArray.append(contentsOf: beacons)
            for beacon in beacons {
                print("info=\(beacon.proximityUUID.uuidString)major=\(beacon.major) minor=\(beacon.minor) accuracy=\(beacon.accuracy) rssi=\(beacon.rssi)")

                self.baconsListTV.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
extension iBeaconListVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return beaconsArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let beacon = beaconsArray[indexPath.row]
        let cell = self.baconsListTV.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "beaconsCell") as! BeaconsCell
        cell.IDLabel.text = "UUID: " + String(beacon.proximityUUID.uuidString)
        cell.detailLabel.text = "Details: Major = " + String(beacon.major.intValue) + " Minor = " +  String(beacon.minor.intValue) + " Distance: " + String(beacon.proximity.rawValue)
        cell.infoLabel.text = "RSSI: " + String(beacon.rssi)
        return cell
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```